# How can I make imports in pythontex which apply to all sessions?

Tags: pythontex

How can I make imports in pythontex which apply to all sessions? Consider for example the following pseudocode. I want to have separate sessions sessionA and sessionB, but want to import in both sessions the numpy library. How can I globally do this such that the import statement applies to all sessions?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}[ApplyToAllSessions]
  from numpy import *
\end{pycode}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}[sessionA]
  #from numpy import *
  a = 5
\end{pycode}


\begin{pycode}[sessionB]
  #from numpy import *
  a = 5
\end{pycode}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add common code with the command `\pythontexcustomc` or the `pythontexcustomcode` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\pythontexcustomc[begin]{py}{
  from numpy import *
}

\begin{pycode}[sessionA]
  #from numpy import *
  a = 5
\end{pycode}


\begin{pycode}[sessionB]
  #from numpy import *
  a = 5
\end{pycode}


\end{document}
```